# Checking if http is success or fail Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I would like to ask if how can I handle if the http request that I made succcess or failed in my component. I do the dispatching of data through a reducer from my actions(http). What I want to achieve here is after the http request the component will notify if its succeeds or fail so I can do some other things if the http request is done.

Component:

```
class BoardAdd extends React.Component {


    addBoard(formProps) {

        // This is where my HTTP request
        this.props.addBoard(formProps);

        // After I call the this.props.addBoard(formProps). I want to check if it succeeds or fail
    }

    render() {

        const { error, handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <Col lg={3}>
                <a href="javascript:;" className={style.boardItemAdd} onClick={this.openAddBoardModal.bind(this)}>
                    <div className={[style.boardItemContainer,style.boardItemGray].join(' ')}>
                        Create New Board
                    </div>
                </a>

                <Modal show={this.state.boardAddModalShow} onHide={this.closeAddBoardModal.bind(this)} bsSize="small" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-sm">
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-sm">Create Board</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.addBoard.bind(this))}>

                            <Field name="name" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="What are you organizing" />
                            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                        </form>

                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>

            </Col>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        data: state.board.data,
        success: state.board.success
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addBoard })(form(BoardAdd));
```

Action:

```
export function addBoard(data){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.post(`${API_URL}/boards`,
            {
                name: data.name
            }
        )
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status === 201){
                dispatch({ type: ADD_BOARD_SUCCESS, data: response.data.result });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { ADD_BOARD_SUCCESS,ADD_BOARD_FAIL} from 'constant/board.jsx';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: {},
    error_message: '',
    success: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action = {}) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_BOARD_SUCCESS:
            return {
                data: action.data,
                success: true,
                error_message: ''
            };
        case ADD_BOARD_FAIL:
            return {
                data: {},
                success: false,
                error_message: action.error_message
            };
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the default reducer state look like? Double check the dot notation in mapStateToProps. If it's spelled wrong the prop will be undefined. Should it be `state.board.data` or something else?

Comment: Hi KeithA, i've editted my post, adding the codes of my reducer.

Comment: What is the actual response from your request? Are you certain `response.data.result` isn't undefined?

Comment: Looks like i'm going with the componentWillReceiveProps to check if the mapStateToProps change. Its this the way in react do this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you're asking here. Are you trying to debug why your `state.data` is undefined right now? Or are you trying to implement a way of handling the case when `state.data` is undefined, from within your component?

Comment: What I want to achieve here whatever the return of the actions. will notify the component if its success or fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to notify your component whether it was a success or a failure is to have your action return a promise. So your action would look like this:

```
export function addBoard(data){
    return function(dispatch){
        return axios.post(`${API_URL}/boards`,
            {
                name: data.name
            }
        )
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status === 201){
                const result = response.data.result;
                dispatch({ type: ADD_BOARD_SUCCESS, data: result });
                return result;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your component you can do this:

```
addBoard(formProps) {

    this.props.addBoard(formProps).then((result) => {
        console.log("Success!", result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

You should probably also handle the `catch` in your action, if you want to dispatch a `ADD_BOARD_FAIL` on an error, but then you'd have to rethrow that error if you still want to catch it in the component.

Comment: I tried this a while ago but its gives me an error 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

Comment: It's because you forgot to actually return the promise from axios. This line:  `return axios.post(..`

Comment: Hey Man, you're such a great help that do the job. Before this I was resorting to componentWillReceiveProps but I don't know if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: No problem. That's what SO is here for. Doing this in `componentWillReceiveProps` would be a bad practice, I'd say. Handle as much of this as possible in the action function itself, by dispatching the `ADD_BOARD_FAIL`-action in the catch block.

Comment: Hey Man, I did a catch function in my action to return an ADD_BOARD_FAIL. In my action it goes to the catch function when there a 401 error. But in the component it goes to the then function not in the catch? Any Ideas?

Comment: When you use catch, you essentially handle the error, i.e. you make the error go away. The catch basically makes the promise resolve, which is why any `then` after the catch, is being called. To pass the error on, you can rethrow it in the catch block like this `catch(error => { throw error; })`. In your case, the `throw error;`-line should come after you've dispatched the `ADD_BOARD_FAIL` action. I wouldn't recommended rethrowing the error to be caught in the component, unless you absolutely have to. Use your redux error state whenever possible instead.